# Archlinux wrong localtime

Tags: arch-linux, date-time, ntp

Here is datetimectl output, Why local time is not set to Universal time? And I have enable ntpd service.
The local time should be Sun 2013-08-11 21:45:21 UTC.

```
     Local time:  Mon 2013-08-12 05:45:21 CST
  Universal time: Sun 2013-08-11 21:45:21 UTC
        RTC time: Sun 2013-08-11 21:45:21
        Timezone: Asia/Shanghai (CST, +0800)
     NTP enabled: yes
NTP synchronized: yes
 RTC in local TZ: no
      DST active: n/a
```

By the way , My pc is equiped with dual System(archlinux/win7).

Comment: It's hard to know what's wrong without knowing when those time stamps were taken. Can you provide what you expect local time to be?

Comment: Everything seems ok: UTC Sunday 21h -> Local time (+8h) Monday 5h. What local time do you expect?

Comment: The UTC time is the right time in my time zone.

Comment: @Nicolas Do you mean the UTC time is not correctly? It should be 8 hours before?

Comment: @jilen I don't know if your UTC time is good or not (just compare on internet to be sure). I just want to say, as you choose the Asia/Shangai timezone your localtime will be equal to the UTC time +8H

Comment: @Nicolas OK, seems the utc time is not correctly. I misunderstood the UTC time, I just think it is the time of +8(Asia/Shanghai).

Comment: @user606723 my real local time was expected to be the UTC time display in the question description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows always automatically set the BIOS/RTC time by `localtime`.
Linux on the other hand have different approach, it always set the BIOS/RTC time to `UTC`.

To make arch-linux using localtime then type:

```
timedatectl set-local-rtc 1
```

or to revert to UTC,

```
timedatectl set-local-rtc 0
```

More info on [Time - ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Time)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to be sure of your TimeZone. If it's well Asia/Shanghai, you will have a different of +8 hours between the UTC and your local time.
It's normal, UTC time means universal time: the same for everyone. Although local time is the time of your country/city and it depends where you live.
So, only the people who live near the Greenwich meridian (+0H) have the same UTC and local time.
In my understanding, your time system works well. You misunderstood what UTC and local time are.